# Putting a shape behind links using div

Tags: html, css

So I have recently been working on a school assignment using HTML. I am trying to create a nav bar on the left-hand side of the screen and put a shape behind it using the DIV function. Please keep in mind I am new to reasonably new to coding HTML. The cart is static.  Heres the code:

```css
.nav {
  line-height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #ea9999;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<table width="100%" ">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <table width="200">
      <div class="nav">

           This is where the problem is(I think)

          <a href="index.html">
         <p><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Like a Veggie Logo"></p>
             <tr><td><a href="services.html">Services <a/></td></tr>
             <tr><td><a href="products.html"> Our Products<a/></td></tr>
             <tr><td><a href="order.html">Order</td></tr>
             <tr><td><a href="about.html">About Us</td></tr>

           </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well done on your development journey. I might not answer your question but this will help set you in the right direction. However I have noticed that your HTML for example is broken. Broken HTML makes styling hard and also is bad for accessibility (make the web friendly for the people with impairments).

I suggest that your markup is refactored. This is a sample refactor of the code you have above. However it can be made better.

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <table width="200">
          <tr>
              <td>
                 <div class="nav">This is where the problem is(I think)<a href="index.html"><p><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Like a Veggie Logo" /></p></a>
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td><a href="services.html">Services </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td><a href="products.html"> Our Products</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td><a href="order.html">Order</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td><a href="about.html">About Us</a></td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In my code snippet,

1. I have closed `<a>` tags properly with `</a>` unlike where you closed with ` the slash comes before the element tag.
2. Inserted a `<tr></tr>` in the table then `<div></div>` this is the correct html structure for table. Please revisit this at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

You do not have to use tables to get that structure you want. You can use simple `<div>` then style it to reduce the markup and also increase your page load speed. The less markup, the faster the page load.

Try this HTML5 code

```css
nav {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/57426/paprika-vegetables-colorful-food-57426.jpeg?dl&fit=crop&w=200&h=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">
      <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Like a Veggie Logo">
      </a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services<a/></li>
    <li><a href="products.html"> Our Products<a/></li>
    <li><a href="order.html">Order<a/></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us<a/></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted in the comment.

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful.Thank you for your time to answer the question!

Comment: I am glad it does help.